# Extracting string between 2 strings with bash shell script

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

I've seen questions similar to this, but none of the solutions seem to work in this case. I have a text file that looks something like this

```
START-OF-FILE
RUNDATE=20140910
FIRMNAME=dl
FILETYPE=pc
REPLYFILENAME=TEST
DERIVED=yes
PROGRAMFLAG=oneshot
SECID=ISIN
SECMASTER=yes
PROGRAMNAME=getdata
START-OF-FIELDS
ISSUER
START-OF-DATA
US345370CN85|0|4|FORD MOTOR COMPANY|FORD MOTOR COMPANY| | |
US31679BAC46|0|4|FIFTH STREET FINANCE COR|FIFTH STREET FINANCE COR| | |
END-OF-DATA
END-OF-FILE
```

I'm trying to write a bash shell script to extract only the text between "START-OF-DATA" and "END-OF-DATA" excluding both of these. So output i'm looking for would look like this

```
US345370CN85|0|4|FORD MOTOR COMPANY|FORD MOTOR COMPANY| | |
US31679BAC46|0|4|FIFTH STREET FINANCE COR|FIFTH STREET FINANCE COR| | |
```

The code i've written so far looks like this

```
while read line
do
    name=$line

    echo $name | sed -e 's/START-OF-DATA\(.*\)END-OF-DATA/\1/'

done < $1
```

and running it from bash like

```
./script.sh file.txt
```

where script.sh is what I have saved the shell script as and file.txt is the text file above that it reads. At the moment it just reads and echoes the entire file. I'm guessing its something silly in my syntax. Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk '/START-OF-DATA/{p=1;next} /END-OF-DATA/{p=0;exit} p' file
US345370CN85|0|4|FORD MOTOR COMPANY|FORD MOTOR COMPANY| | |
US31679BAC46|0|4|FIFTH STREET FINANCE COR|FIFTH STREET FINANCE COR| | |
```

Or using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/START-OF-DATA/,/END-OF-DATA/{/START-OF-DATA\|END-OF-DATA/!p;}' file
US345370CN85|0|4|FORD MOTOR COMPANY|FORD MOTOR COMPANY| | |
US31679BAC46|0|4|FIFTH STREET FINANCE COR|FIFTH STREET FINANCE COR| | |
```

Comment: That's great. Exactly what I was looking for... You guys are quick off the mark I must say :) thanks again

Answer (score 2):

In order to make your solution work you could make a marker when you hit "START-OF-DATA" that reads "True" (or similar), and then end it when you hit "END-OF-DATA". Using this marker you could tell echo to print when the marker reads "True" (when you are inside the relevant block of text).

...or you could use sed:

```
sed -n '/START-OF-DATA/,/END-OF-DATA/ { //!p }' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply bryn. Your solution works perfectly. I had to upvote @anubhava as his reply was a little bit quicker. Thanks though. Have the script working fine now. Regards

Comment: Hi bryn. Your [tag:sed] command line is nicer than [anubhava's one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25786380/938111). But a bit cryptic for me: I am wondering what `//` means in `{ //!p }`. Please give some explanations or links to websites explaning this. Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add the perlish `grep` way, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file):

```
grep -Pzo "(?s)START-OF-DATA.*END-OF-DATA" "$1"
```

This still includes the `START-OF-DATA` and `END-OF-DATA` markers. To get rid of them, the pattern has to become a bit less readable:

```
grep -Pzo "(?s)(?<=START-OF-DATA\n).*(?=\nEND-OF-DATA)"
```

`(?<=START-OF-DATA\n)` and `(?=\nEND-OF-DATA)` are *look-around assertions* as described in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns), i.e. they are used for matching, but not included in the result.

Comment: Nice to use prep, but the lines `START-OF-DATA` and `END-OF-DATA` are printed :-/ Please try to improve your command line to avoid printing these two lines. Have fun :-) Cheers

Comment: @olibre: Thanks for pointing that out. I added the improved command line.