# Why does grep return nothing?

Tags: regex, grep

I'm somewhat at ease with regex, but not with grep particularly, and can't figure out why the following regex returns nothing:

```
wget -qO- 'http://www.acme.com/index.html' | grep -iPo '(?s)(^<div class="titlebar">.+?<div class="colleft">)'
```

I prepended (?s) because the catch-all ".+?" includes carriage-returns (either CRLF, CR, or LF, depending on how the text was saved).

Any idea why it doesn't work as expected?

Thank you.

Comment: Because neither of those class names appears anywhere in the page that `wget` returned? What is `(?s)` doing?

Comment: Because he is wicked?

Comment: `(?s)` enables the feature that `.` can match a newline. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html -- not useful here since grep is a line-oriented tool.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I used ?s because this answer says that grep supports multiline with -P : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file

Comment: Show sample input (i.e. output from wget) and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is line-oriented, so if there are newlines between the tags, grep can't find it. You'll want:

```
wget -qO- 'http://website.invalid/index.html' |
perl -0777 -nE 'say for /(^<div class="titlebar">.+?<div class="colleft">)/msg'
```

Comment: Thanks. To avoid installing Perl (appliance with little memory), I tried pcregrep, but it returns nothing : pcregrep -M "<title>(.+)</title>" input.html

Comment: What tools do you have available? sed/awk/... ?