# grep is returning a match when not expected

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I am running a java program which throws an exception. I am piping the run's output to a grep command where I am checking for a pattern which does not exist, however grep keeps returning a match.

```
0,2,468.000000
1,2,305.000000
2,5,2702.000000
3,3,1672.000000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at TestConverter.processPayments(TestConverter.java:113)
    at TestConverter.processFile(TestConverter.java:131)
    at TestConverter.main(TestConverter.java:142)
```

I am running the following command:

```
java -classpath TestConverter.jar TestConverter test_xml.xml | grep "stringthatdoesnotmatch*"
```

I get the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at TestConverter.processPayments(TestConverter.java:113)
    at TestConverter.processFile(TestConverter.java:131)
    at TestConverter.main(TestConverter.java:142)
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Furthermore, my end goal is to check if the output contains the following pattern:

```
*java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException*ArrayList.java:653*TestConverter.java:142*
```

Comment: Are you sure the exception output isn't going to stderr instead of stdout?

Comment: Try piping STDERR to grep, too: `java -classpath TestConverter.jar TestConverter test_xml.xml |& grep "stringthatdoesnotmatch*"`

Comment: @StephenNewell Not sure where it is going. But I feel like it may be going to stderr. How can I grep stderr?

Comment: @zwer I tried that and got a ```-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'```

Comment: @sophist_pt - That's weird, bash should recognize the `|&` shorthand. Either way, try: `java -classpath TestConverter.jar TestConverter test_xml.xml 2>&1 | grep "stringthatdoesnotmatch*"`

Comment: @zwer That seems to be working, however I am now trying to make sure that grep checks for a match that guarantees it contains ```*java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException*ArrayList.java:653*TestConverter.java:142*``` Do you know how I can achieve this?

Comment: @sophist_pt - `grep` works on line-by-line basis by default. There are several approaches that you can use for multiline matches, check answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/152708)

Comment: @zwer Thanks for the help. I piped the output to xargs and did the grep and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 3):

You're actually *not* getting a match. What you have to understand is the difference between standard *output* and standard *error.*

The Java program is writing its normal output to the former and exceptions to the latter, but *both* those streams are initially attached to your terminal device.

So, when you add a pipeline:

```
program | grep xyzzy
```

the `|` character will divert the standard *output* of `program` to the standard input of `grep`. That will then filter out any lines not containing `xyzzy`, and pass the rest to *its* standard output, the terminal in this case.

The standard *error* of `program` is still connected directly to the terminal so will appear there regardless of what `grep` does.

If you want the `grep` program to capture both output *and* error of `program, combine them first:

```
program 2>&1 | grep xyzzy
```

That `2>&1` means take what was destined for stream 2 (standard error) and instead send it to stream 1 (standard output). Then the `|` can take *all* of the output/error coming from `program`.