# How to append & sort multiple set of lines from multiple files to result file using shell script?

Tags: shell, sorting, logging, trim

I have multiple log files, which has format as below -

**A.txt**

```
18-05-23 11:28:25.939 ##Start
18-05-23 11:28:25.940 Unique ID - ABC123
18-05-23 11:28:25.941 ##End
18-05-23 11:28:25.942 ##Start
18-05-23 11:28:25.943 Unique ID - PQR123
18-05-23 11:28:25.944 ##End
18-05-23 11:28:25.945 ##Start
18-05-23 11:28:25.946 Unique ID - MNO123
18-05-23 11:28:25.947 ##End
```

**B.txt**

```
18-05-23 11:28:25.949 ##Start
18-05-23 11:28:25.950 Unique ID - ABC123
18-05-23 11:28:25.951 ##End
18-05-23 11:28:25.952 ##Start
18-05-23 11:28:25.953 Unique ID - PQR123
18-05-23 11:28:25.954 ##End
18-05-23 11:28:25.955 ##Start
18-05-23 11:28:25.956 Unique ID - MNO123
18-05-23 11:28:25.947 ##End
```

Here, I want to create C.txt file which contains only **ABC123** information starting from **##Start** line to **##End** line also in **sorted order**. check below expected output for detailed understanding.

Expected **C.txt**

```
18-05-23 11:28:25.939 ##Start
18-05-23 11:28:25.940 Unique ID - ABC123
18-05-23 11:28:25.941 ##End
18-05-23 11:28:25.949 ##Start
18-05-23 11:28:25.950 Unique ID - ABC123
18-05-23 11:28:25.951 ##End
```

Please suggest- how can I achieve this using shell scripting ?

Comment: Will it always be 3 lines: "Start", then "Unique ID", then "End"?  Or will there sometimes be extra lines in the middle?  If it's always 3 lines, then you can do a `grep` and `sort`, like this:  `grep -A 1 -B 1 ABC123 A.txt B.txt | sort > C.txt`

Comment: @TimJohns thanks for response. There will be extra lines in the middle. I have just given example of 3 lines.

Comment: If the next pattern starts before the end of a pattern from another log file, do you want A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 or A1 A2 B1 A3 B2 B3 ? (assuming A1=#start, A2=#Unique Id, A3=#end from a.txt, B1=#start, B2=#Unique Id, B3=#end from b.txt, and the B1 timestamp occurs between A2 and A3 ?

Comment: I can't think know any way to do this without resorting to a more powerful programming language (Perl or Python are the usual candidates for this) or a special utility for multiline matching not always present in a standard Unix installation ( such as pcregrep, mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file )

Comment: This is a Perl implementation of what you want: https://github.com/fbergo/examples/blob/master/logpat.pl , which will sort in A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 order. If you want the other ordering, just pass the output file through `sort` on the command line.

Comment: @FBergo There will be no scenario where B1 comes in between A2 & A3. Pattern will be A1=#start, A2=#Unique Id, A3=#end every time.
Also,your implemented Perl script is very nice. but it is not working in case of below scenario =>
18-05-23 11:28:25.939 ##Start
18-05-23 11:28:25.940 Some text Unique ID - ABC123 Sometext
18-05-23 11:28:25.941 ##End