# A regex to detect a word and a string that is not enclosed in double quotes

Tags: regex

I have tried to write a regular expression for the an example code to use in grep search.

My requirement is to get string output that matches only the below

execute(any word here)

For eg.

```
execute(any)
execute(math)
```

and the results should not output

```
execute("any")
execute("math")
```

I already tried the following, but the problem with this is that it outputs everything and doesn't give me the required solution.

```
grep -E '^execute\(*([^)]+)*\)'
```

I expect my output to be execute(math) or execute(s) and not

execute("math") or execute("s")

Comment: Can there be a single double quote? What about `execute(m"at"h)`?

Comment: `grep -Eo '^execute\(*([^)]+)*\)' file | sed 's/"//g' > output_file`

Comment: @Thefourthbird, no single quotes are not allowed.Anyways thanks for your time !

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it outputted empty. Nothing happened. Anyways thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your limited sample data, this should work:

```
^execute\([a-zA-Z]+\)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/S4owrs/2

Comment: Thanks very much for the solution ! it worked, but somehow i couldn't make it work on my terminal `grep -E '^execute\([a-zA-Z]+\)$'` by typing just that.  This `grep execute\([a-zA-Z] *.lib` somehow got me closer to what i wanted.  Anyways appreciate your time. Do you have any idea why the first version didn't work ?

Comment: @user1753356 I'm not sure I don't have a Linux box to test with. Try it with the `-E` option for extended regexp. You can also try simply removing the anchors `^` and `$` and see if that makes a difference. It's possible you need `pcregrep` per https://stackoverflow.com/q/152708/2191572. Above all else I suggest reading the man pages for whatever tool you use.

Comment: Awesome, your link was really helpful !! i tried this  `find . -iname '*.lib' | xargs pcregrep -M 'execute\([a-zA-Z]+\)'` from the link you shared and it worked ! Have a nice day! :)

Comment: @user1753356 You're welcome, I'm glad you found my post and comments useful!