# How can I match an exact pattern with sed -n

Tags: sed

I have a file test.txt

```
---
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
subjects:
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: bla
```

And need this output with sed (just the line that matches the exact pattern)

```
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
```

sed -n '/kind: ClusterRole/,/metadata/p' test.txt

```
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: bla
```

is showing ClusterRole, ClusterRoleBinding and additional indented ClusterRole

```
sed -n '/kind: ClusterRole\b/,/metadata/p' test.txt
sed -n '/\<kind: ClusterRole\>/,/metadata/p' test.txt
```

Both of the above output to nothing what am I doing wrong? 
just so it's clear and I'm not getting any grep -B 2 suggestions ;-) this is an example file, the original file is a lot bigger and has hundreds of ClusterRoles so I need to figure out how to match the exact pattern.

Thank you!

lema

Comment: It's not very clear why you would want to do this (you don't need sed to produce the output as described). However: `sed -n '/^kind: ClusterRole$/,${1,/^metadata:$/p}' file.txt`

Comment: or `sed -n '/^kind: ClusterRole$/,${p;/^metadata:$/q}' file.txt` to not waste time reading the rest of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include start-of-line (`^`) and end-of-line (`$`) in your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to search the exact multiple lines, then you can achieve it using `pcregrep`

```
pcregrep -M 'kind: ClusterRole(\n)metadata:' test.txt
```

where -M, --multiline allow patterns to match more than one line.

More details can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep) SO post.

**Edit:**

You can also use `grep`

```
grep -Pazo 'kind: ClusterRole\nmetadata:' test.txt
```

Reference: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/152755/3125022) SO post

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 'N;/^kind: ClusterRole\nmetadata:$/p;D' file
```

Append the next line and print the lines if it matches. Delete the first line and repeat.

If you only want the first match, use:

```
sed -n 'N;/^kind: ClusterRole\nmetadata:$/{p;q};D' file
```