# grep a sentence with a matching pattern

Tags: unix, grep

I am trying to grep a sentence consists of multiple new lines, different alphanumeric characters.
The below kind of lines are many in number in each file.
Any help is welcome and greatly appreciated !!!

For Example:

```
TRC_LOG (FLAG, INFO, TAG,
                    "hELLO wORLD %s \r\n",
                                        fUN (u4));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly don't post samples or your efforts(in form of code) in images form, that is NOT encouraged on SO. Please edit your question with text samples by wrapping CODE TAGS on them.

Comment: sure, removing it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep/2686705

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file

Comment: Found solution in the below link, but it is with awk, (awk is not showing filename where it found, but OK), Thanks for the help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file